# SwiftUI only showing a black screen

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, swiftui

I had created a few projects in SwiftUI that were perfectly fine, before I went on holiday around 2 weeks ago. When I got back, I updated Xcode and my iPhone.

The code for SwiftUI is not relevant as it was all working perfectly fine before. All I am getting on multiple projects tested is just a plain black screen.

What could be causing all my projects just to show a black screen, when they worked before updating Xcode and my device?

Versions:

> My device - 13.0 beta 4
>
> Simulators don't work - not sure on versions
>
> Xcode-beta - 11.0 beta 4 (11M374r)

Comment: “Simulators don't work” Huh?

Comment: @matt The issue is fixed now but I meant that it doesn't work on the simulator, similar to my device.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In `SceneDelegate.swift` replace

```
let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
self.window = window
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

with

```
if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

If you had a `.environtmentObject` attached to `ContentView()` originally, don't forget to add that onto the `ContentView()` in the above code.

When you create a new project in Xcode beta 4, the second code block I posted is what is automatically generated in `SceneDelegate.swift`. The first code block I posted is what was automatically generated in all versions prior to beta 4. As you can see in the second block, the window is now initialized with the `scene` provided by the `SceneDelegate` function `scene(scene:, session:, connectionOptions:)` instead of a `CGRect` (`UIScreen.main.bounds`).

Comment: “The first code block I posted is what was automatically generated in all versions prior to beta 4” That would explain the black screen, but I’ve never seen that code in a SwiftUI app template in any version of Xcode.

Comment: Accidentally had a test environment object in the first block and just now edited it out, but that first block of code is what was automatically generated in all my projects from pre-beta 4, and all of them result in a black screen until I replace it with the second block. @matt

Answer (score 3):

Also if the advice above didn't work, make sure that you have the correct pointer to `SceneDelegate` in your `Info.plist`.

[image: Info.plist]

Comment: This one solves my problem. I was coming from creating a new project on the XCode 13 so I had to manually add the SceneDelegate myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing Xcode and see this [link](https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-changes-in-xcode-11-beta-4) to migrate from Xcode beta 3 to Xcode beta 4

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too after going from beta 3 to 4. I created a new project in beta 4 and copied everything over from the old project and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In your info plist replace this key value -

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                <string>Default Configuration</string>
                <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

The SceneDelegate will looks like below --

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
}
```

The AppDelegate will be -

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {}
```