# Set rootViewController iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, uiwindow, rootview

After upgrading Xcode a critical part of my application has stopped working.

When my app launches I run a function to check boolean flags and set the correct rootViewController.

But the code I have been using to set this has now stopped working

```
class func setLoginAsInitialViewContoller(window:UIWindow) {
    print("SET LOGIN") 
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController")
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    window.rootViewController = controller
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Specifically when the app gets the the second last line `window.rootViewController = controller` it crashes with a `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` error.

The above function is in a class called `Utilities.swift` and I am calling the function from within my `AppDelegate.swift` as shown below:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var storyboard: UIStoryboard? = nil

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
        Utilities.decideInitialViewController(window: self.window!)

        return true
    }
```

Any solutions or fixes on how I can set the root controller is much appreciated.

Thank!

Comment: Is that the full error message in console?

Comment: have you tried adding exception breakpoints to get more information about the crash?

Comment: there should be more information about what exception happened.

Comment: @Larme yes that's the full error, It gives me 'libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException' followed by '(lldb)'

Comment: Nothing before? Like a almost the same one, with uppercase at some letters and "NSUncaugthException"  instead of "NSException"?

Comment: @Larme not a single thing before! Very frustrating that its the only error its giving me.. here's the console log https://imgur.com/a/ixgP1oX

Comment: Strange to set the `controller.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen` on the rootVC? no? Could it be the issue? Also, what are the values of the differents object in the debugguer when it crashes. Are some nil?

Comment: No that doesn't cause any issues, I've removed that and still having same problem..

Comment: @Larme I have updated my question with some further details

Comment: In iOS 13, window is now part of `SceneDelegate`. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56515686/3411787)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because AppDelegate doesn't have `window` property anymore.
Now you must use SceneDelegate's `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` method to change root view controller.
Like shown in this example:

```swift
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

        // Instantiate UIWindow with scene
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
        // Assign window to SceneDelegate window property
        self.window = window
        // Set initial view controller from Main storyboard as root view controller of UIWindow
        self.window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
        // Present window to screen
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

It is available in **SceneDelegate.swift** file in your project

It will have delegate method :

> func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession,
>   options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)

**Example**

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession,
 options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {


if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {

    self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene) 

    let initialViewController = 
        storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController")            
        self.window!.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

}
```

Comment: where to set rootViewController for notification Clicked. Earlier i was doing this in app_delegate  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) { .  But on setting rootViewController it is found nil.

Comment: This solved an unrelated problem for me. I used to be able to grab the rootVC in AppDelegate by accessing keyWindow which is deprecated now. Sure enough when opening the app from a url, keywindow is none and the rootVC is some on the windowScene object. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In **viewDidAppear** you can set root:-

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            print(self.view.window)
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController
            self.view.window?.rootViewController = vc
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking to create a couple of extensions to change the root view controller and need to support both delegate types (UISceneDelegate and AppDelegate), here's a couple:

```
    extension UIViewController {
        var appDelegate: AppDelegate {
        return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    }
    
    var sceneDelegate: SceneDelegate? {
        guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
            let delegate = windowScene.delegate as? SceneDelegate else { return nil }
         return delegate
    }
}
```

And if you're in need of an extension to reach the UIWindow from a ViewController with iOS12 and iOS13 Support:

```
extension UIViewController {
    
    var window: UIWindow? {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
                let delegate = windowScene.delegate as? SceneDelegate, let window = delegate.window else { return nil }
                   return window
        }
        
        guard let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = delegate.window else { return nil }
        return window
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, Can you share the code how to use these extensions? Let's say I have to set "LoginVC" as my rootViewController. FYI: My deployment target is iOS 13.0

Comment: @Bhanuteja sure with these extensions you can do something like : self.window?.rootViewController =  LoginVC for example.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to use [`ScenceDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/258/). In `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:`, creates a new UIWindow, sets the window’s `rootViewController` and makes this window the `key` window.
- If you don't want to use `ScenceDelegate`, you can try to remove it [by following this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60329391/4026902).