# Get different object when debug on push to NavigationController and ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift

In my project i use coordinator pattern to manage each viewController but i can't set coordinator to viewController for some reason.

So i try to debug an object before push to navigationController stack and on viewDidload and i get the different object from address

[image]

that make coordinator that i set to viewController equal nil

How can i fix that?
PS. this is my github if you want to see all my project

https://github.com/goodboygb1/SanarmMai.git

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your `setupMainCoordinator` from `AppDelegate` to `SceneDelegate` like this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: in my company project we always use appDelegate so why i have to move this function to scene delegate?

Comment: @PoomWutthidech This is new since iOS 13, see more discussions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58082743/set-rootviewcontroller-ios-13